# Array empty or filled depending on if expression

Tags: php, laravel

I am having some trouble I can not find a solution to.

```
     $isusersubscribed = ($user->onPlan('user') OR $user->onPlan('admin'));

     // If no subscription exists, create a new one

        if (!$isusersubscribed) {

        try {

            $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->name)->create(request('stripeToken'));

            } catch (\Exception $e){
                    return response()->json(
                        ['status' => $e->getMessage()], 422
                    );
            }
        }

    // Then prepare data for the Vue components
    $subscriptions = $user->subscriptions->all();
```

The $subscriptions should return a collection of the users subscriptions. However, it returns an empty array even if the code inside the if-statement runs and a subscription is created.

If I remove the line

```
    $isusersubscribed = $user->onPlan('user') OR $user->onPlan('admin');
```

and replace the expression inside the if with "true", I get the subscriptions correctly.

Can anyone please help me?

UPDATE:

It works if I use

```
        $subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

I have no idea why this does not work:

```
         $subscriptions = $user->subscriptions->all();
```

Like I said, this relationship does work if I just use if (1 == 1) before the block.

Comment: check `$subscribed`  with `empty()` instead of `NOT TRUE`

Comment: But it is a boolean. Returns true if any of the two conditions are true, false if user is not on a subscription. I have tried $isusersubscribed == false also. It recognizes that this is true, and runs the block and creates a subscription. But the $subscriptions collection is then empty afterwards

Comment: I also tried if (empty($user->subscriptions->all())). It runs the code, but then the $subscriptions is empty afterwards.

If I run if (1==1), everything works.

Comment: Got it working by using

$subscriptions = Subscription::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

I have no idea why it would not work with the regular relationship when using the if-expression. It works everywhere else.

Comment: @Bergkamp10 I believe your condition is the problem. Replace `OR` with `||` and it should work. It is because `=` has higher priority than `OR` which means `$a = false or true;` will evaluate to `false`. Avoid using `OR` and `AND` unless you know what are you doing :)

Comment: I just don't see how that can be the problem, as it runs the block correctly (only if there is no subscription). The subscription is created successfully in the database, it just does not show in the array when trying to get it using $subscriptions = $user->subscriptions->all();

Comment: Still, now you have one less bug in your code :)
Try to replace `$subscriptions = $user->subscriptions->all();` with `$subscriptions = $user->subscriptions->get();`. Not tested tho.

Comment: Yes, thanks :) No. Does not work with get() either. But I have it working now using Subscription::